Were David's 7.5 years in Hebron only restricted to his rule over Judah?
My question initially revolves around the discrepancy in the length of the reign of Ishbosheth and David, who, although parallel, reigned 2 and 7.5 years respectively before David conquered Jerusalem:

2 Samuel 2:10-11 (KJV)
Ish-bosheth Saul's son was forty years old when he began to reign over Israel, and reigned two years. But the house of Judah followed David. And the time that David was king in Hebron over the house of Judah was seven years and six months.

We have a 5 1/2 year difference here, so either the 2 years of Ishbosheth's reign should be allocated to the end of David's reign, with a gap of 5.5 years before, or else of the 7.5 years that David reigned in Hebron, 2 of these he reigned exclusively over Judah, and another 5.5 already over all Israel, before the conquest of Jerusalem.
It seems illogical to me that it would take so long for Ish-bosheth to take office as king, especially at such a critical moment when a rival king was taking over the government of a tribe, but I don't want to debate that exactly here. My question revolves around the second scenario, since the only obstacle to it is in the statement in 2 Samuel 5:

2 Samuel 5:4-5 (KJV)
David was thirty years old when he began to reign, and he reigned forty years. In Hebron he reigned over Judah seven years and six months: and in Jerusalem he reigned thirty and three years over all Israel and Judah.

This seems to imply that the entire 7.5 year period should apply solely to David's reign over Judah, and that his entire reign over the united Israel occurred already in Jerusalem.
Is there some loophole in the original construction of this Hebrew verse or even in other classical versions, such as the LXX, that allows the theory I presented earlier, that the 7.5 years encompassed both the reign over Judah and part of the reign over the united Israel, still in Hebron and before the conquest of Jerusalem, to be true?

First, I would point out that Saul's reign was not a unified kingship in the first place. He struggled to consolidate his authority and some territories remained in Canaanite or Philistine hands. When Saul famously attacked the Amalekites, he mustered  200,000 Israelites but only 10,000 men of Judah. (1 Sam 15:4) This indicates that his power in Judah was limited indeed.
Now to David: Prior to become king of "all Israel" David's control was mostly over Judah rather than the northern tribes. However, even in Judah he did not conquer Jerusalem, for example, until seven years after becoming king in Hebron.
2 Samuel 5:5

in Hebron he was king over Judah seven years and six months, and in
Jerusalem he was king thirty-three years over all Israel

We should also take with a grain of salt that David truly ruled over "all Israel and Judah" for 40 years beginning when he was 30. The biblical writers like round numbers, and the more one delves into the details of David's reign, the more  it is apparent that the northern tribes never fully accepted his rule. The rebellion of Absalom (2 Samuel 15:6) and of Sheba (2 Samuel 20:1) both received substantial northern support.
A hint about the OP's main question is found in 2 Sam. 3:1, which takes place immediately after Joab's defeat of Abner during the reign of Ishbosheth.

1 There followed a long war between the house of Saul and the house of
David, in which David grew ever stronger, but the house of Saul ever
weaker... 6 During the war between the house of Saul and the house of
David, Abner was gaining power in the house of Saul.

Scholars have noted that 1/2 Samuel comprise several sources that a later editor has woven into the narrative as we have it. An introduction to the NABRE version says:

These books include independent blocks (e.g., the Ark Narrative [1 Sm
4:1–7:1], Saul’s rise to power [1 Sm 9:1–11:15], David’s ascendancy
over Saul [1 Sm 16–31], the Succession Narrative [2 Sm 9–20; 1 Kgs
1–2]), which the editor shaped into three narrative cycles, the last
two marked by transitional passages in 1 Sm 13:1 and 2 Sm 1:1.

Conclusion: The Bible does not give us an detailed timeline. It seems that Samuel's sources differed in terms of how long Ishbosheth ruled and, as is often the cause with biblical writers, the author/editor faithfully reported them, even though this leaves us with a quandary.

I will supplement this answer by pointing out that Ishbosheth ruled from Mahanaim immediately after the death of Saul (2 Samuel ch 2 vv8-9), and that the transfer to Jerusalem (ch5 v6) is not related to the fall of Ishbosheth and can easily be placed five years later. Also "ruling", in that social context, need mean only that they accepted him as war-leader and looked to him to settle legal disputes (ch15 vv1-4).

So does this mean that yes, it is possible that David reigned over "all Israel" while still in Hebron?

A brief comment on 2 Sam. 3:1, which you cited. When I read it for the first time, while studying the case, my first intuition was that perhaps this "long war" could in fact encompass the entire period of 7.5 years, that is, the initial 2, with Ishbosheth, and another 5.5 before the end of war and David's national recognition. But that would mean a 5-year vacancy of power over the 11 tribes, which doesn't seem very logical to me in a context of Philistine invasions

Unless, of course, this long war refers to David's entire 40-year government, after all, as you mentioned, the recognition of David was never in fact totally full

@L.Rodrigues According to 2 Samuel ch5 v1, the other tribes came to Hebron to submit to David. So it looks as though "Ruled Judah from Hebron, ruled all the tribes from Jerusalem" is the over-simplification which is confusing the story.
